# unexpected T_FUNCTION in array_filter

Tags: php, array-filter

I havent touched my code in awhile and just noticed an error.  I cant quite figure out whats causing it.  Here is line 80 which it reports the error at:

```
  75 - $list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $ftp_dir);
  80 - $filtered = array_filter($list, function($file) use ($cpuser) {
  81 - return is_txt($file, $cpuser);
```

Here is the function I have listed outside my while loop to grab this information:

```
function is_txt($file, $cpuser) {
return preg_match('/backup-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_'.$cpuser.'.tar.gz/', $file) > 0;
}
```

EDIT**

Fixed, I just needed to run php 5.3 in my .htaccess

Comment: What version of PHP? Closures were introduced with 5.3.x

Answer (score 0):

The array_filter function doesn't have a closing ")"

```
$filtered = array_filter($list, function($file) use ($cpuser) {
```

-->

```
$filtered = array_filter($list, function($file) use ($cpuser)) {
```